# Why is my Oracle PROCEDURE returning 0 records

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

If I run this static SQL in ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER:

```
SELECT appl_id
     FROM grant_appls where full_appl_num IN( 
 '1R01HL129077-01','2R01HL075494-10A1','2P01HL062426-16') AND SUBPROJECT_ID is not null;
```

I get these results:

```
APPL_ID
8855105
8855112
8855104
8855108
8855109
8855107
8855106
```

Now I write the PROCUDERE and put the Static SQL in there:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_APPLIDS_BY_FULL_GRANT_NUM (
   fullGrantNumList IN VARCHAR2,
applIdRecordSet OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
 OPEN applIdRecordSet FOR
 SELECT appl_id
 FROM grant_appls where full_appl_num IN
 (
     '1R01HL129077-01','2R01HL075494-10A1','2P01HL062426-16'
 ) AND SUBPROJECT_ID is not null;
END GET_APPLIDS_BY_FULL_GRANT_NUM;
```

I could have sworn at one point I was getting results since I have the static comma delimeted list.
But now I can't even get results with this.

The Ouput Variables window has the variable APPLIDRECORDSET but there are no values for APPL_ID.

The final version should look something like this:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_APPLIDS_BY_FULL_GRANT_NUM (
   fullGrantNumList IN VARCHAR2,
   applIdRecordSet OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
 OPEN applIdRecordSet FOR
     SELECT appl_id
     FROM grant_appls where full_appl_num IN
     (
     fullGrantNumList
 ) AND SUBPROJECT_ID is not null;
END GET_APPLIDS_BY_FULL_GRANT_NUM;
```

So of course when I run this I am getting back null:

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR
EXECUTE GET_APPLIDS_BY_FULL_GRANT_NUM("'1R01HL129077-01','2R01HL075494-      10A1','2P01HL062426-16'",:cur);
SELECT :cur FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter `fullGrantNumList` won't be used by Oracle the way you think.  Oracle takes the bind variables and treats it as one value, it doesn't do a text replace like you think.  Here is what is actually happening to your query:

```
select appl_id from grant_appls where full_appl_num in ('''1R01HL129077-01'',''2R01HL075494-      10A1'',''2P01HL062426-16''') amd subproject_id is null;
```

This is actually one of the nice things about bind variables is that they protect you from SQL Injection attacks.

My recommendation would be to either pass in a list of values as a table type or convert the statement to a string and use dynamic SQL to execute it.

[Dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm)

Comment: Yes, I see that.
But the weird thing is to start off with, I'm not actually using the fullGrantNumLIst param passed in.
I'm hard coding it in like this:

<CODE>
    OPEN applIdRecordSet FOR
         SELECT appl_id
         FROM grant_appls where full_appl_num IN
         (
             '1R01HL129077-01','2R01HL075494')
</CODE>
And I get no results.
I thought I had this hard coded version working but I can't get it back.

Comment: Hmm... When I execute the PROC, I just changed the value from: '1R01HL129077-01','2R01HL075494-10A1','2P01HL062426-16'
to: 'Hello'.
And now the hard coded version gives me back my rows:)
Getting closer.

Comment: I am now able to execute from the PL/SQL execute dialogue by passing this:
'''' || ''1R01HL129077-01'',''2R01HL075494-10A1'',''2P01HL062426-16'' || ''''
<br>
But I cannot get this to run:
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR
EXECUTE GET_APPLIDS_BY_FULL_GRANT_NUM('''' || ''1R01HL129077-01'',''2R01HL075494-10A1'',''2P01HL062426-16'' || '''',:cur);
SELECT :cur FROM dual;

Comment: Can you elaborate on the PL/SQL "execute dialogue"?  I'm not sure to what you are referring.